# Dark Axis Line at y = 0 in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is giving me major grid lines, as shown below.

How do I get one dark axis line for just *y = 0*?

```
fig, ax1 = subplots(figsize=(3,6))
ax1.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', color='grey', alpha=0.5)

bound = 20
ylim([-bound,bound])
boxplot(data)

show()
```

[image: box and whisker plot]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a call to `axhline`:

```
axhline(0, color='black')
```

[image]

Comment: For some additional clarity, this function should be called on the figure's axis, so in this specific case: `ax1.axhline(0, color='black')`

Comment: Answer could also link the user manual for `axhline` as that lists all the other arguments besides simply 'color': https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html
Could also mention the equivilent for a vertical line at y=0 using: `axvline`